# I am getting error while trying to load a activity from adapter class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using `NavigationBar` so in one of the fragments i am getting error while implementing click on card view. Although click is working as tested it with toast but using intent to get to another activity is not working.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{minor.da.com.donationapp/minor.da.com.donationapp.SecondPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
        at minor.da.com.donationapp.SecondPage.onCreate(SecondPage.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Hello link to your card view"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|fill"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textAlignment="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:textColor="#f4086172"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ADAPTER CLASS CODE

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class vizAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<vizAdapter.Myviewholder>      {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

List<information> data= Collections.emptyList();
public vizAdapter(Context context, List<information> data){
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;

}
@Override
public Myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    Myviewholder holder=new Myviewholder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(Myviewholder holder, int position) {
  information current=data.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class Myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    public  Myviewholder( View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listicon);
        getView(itemView);


    }
}
public View getView(View v){

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i=new Intent(context,SecondPage.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(context,"hello successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: needs your layout code?

Comment: thanks@PhanVănLinh i am new here,thanks for helping.

Comment: @7rocker does the xml in your question is the layout of `SecondPage` activity. if not, please post the `SecondPage` layout

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yes this is the xml of second page .its a blank page with just a textview.when i am clicking on the cardview item which is present inside a fragment then this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should remove `android:textAlignment="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"` in your `TextView`

`config_shortAnimTime` is the duration for animation
To find which property is allowed for `android:textAlignment` please see here
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment
Hope this help you